proof of a statement in wikipedia on tridiagonal matrices?
On the wikipedia article for tridiagonal matrices, it is claimed that:

if a real tridiagonal matrix A satisfies $a_{k,k+1} a_{k+1,k} > 0$ for all $k$, so that the signs of its entries are symmetric, then it is similar to a Hermitian matrix, by a diagonal change of basis matrix.

I am looking for a proof of this statement, or even better, a construction of the diagonal change of basis matrix. (Or even better: a method to calculate the eigenvalues!). The wiki page cites a book of Horn and Johnson, but it seems this is left to an exercise.
Forgive me for just asking for a proof, I am a poor physicist and have stumbled into this problem unwittingly...

Label the elements on the upper diagonal as $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_{n-1}$ and label those on the lower diagonal as $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_{n-1}$. Then $DAD^{-1}$ is symmetric when
$$
D=\operatorname{diag}\left(1,\sqrt{\frac{b_1}{c_1}},\sqrt{\frac{b_1b_2}{c_1c_2}},\ldots,\sqrt{\frac{b_1\cdots b_{n-1}}{c_1\cdots c_{n-1}}}\right).
$$

Nice! Thank you very much!
